# Flask-WTF, unexpected output using macro use of {{ field |safe}} (HTML escaping)

Tags: macros, output, field, flask-wtforms

- When the input is

  [image]
- When then output is

  [image]
- But when I change the input to

  [image]
- My output changes to

  [image]

Please some body explain me why this is happening?
What's the role of {{ field |safe}}?

My App.py code -

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
   name = StringField("Name Of Student",validators = [InputRequired(message 
       = 'Name is missing'),Length(min=5,max=10,message="wrong")])
   email = StringField("email",[validators.Email("Please enter your email 
       address.")])

@app.route('/form', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = ContactForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('macro_output.html',form=form)

    return render_template('main_form.html',form=form)
```

macro_form.html

```
{% macro render_output(field) %}
<p>
{{ field.label}}
{{ field |safe}}
</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

macro_output.html

```
{% from "macro_form.html" import render_field, 
render_ErrorMessage,render_output %}
<html>
<body>
    {{ render_output(form.name)}}
    {{ render_output(form.name.data)}}
    {{ render_output(form.email)}}
    {{ render_output(form.email.data)}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jijna2 filter `safe` treats strings as, well, safe and does not do any pre-formatting by automatically escaping any characters that would otherwise be interpreted as code (in this case HTML code).

So if a variable, say, `form.name.data = <html>` then invoking `{{ form.name.data | safe }}` will embed an html tag (`<html>`) into your HTML, and I expect that the HTML browser parser simply ignores it as an error (you can check the rendered page source). But invoking `{{ form.name.data }}` jinja2 will escape the '<>' characters only 'html' will go into the HTML and therefore be rendered as text.

I would strongly advise against the use of the safe filter for user input, since an arbitrary user could inject code into your page, e.g. `<script> ... </script>`